# What is the difference between $rootScope vs $rootScope.$emit/$broadcast in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, single-page-application

This is my page's structure.

```
// app.html
<wrapper ng-if="initialized && $root.user.type!='guest'">
  <header-component></header-component>
  <div class="app-body">
    <sidebar-component></sidebar-component>
    <main class="main-content" style="height:{{$root.pageHeight}}px; overflow-y: scroll">
      <ng-view></ng-view>
    </main>
    <aside-component></aside-component>
  </div>
</wrapper>
```

Now in ng-view directive I have a controller which needs to pass data to the header-component.
As you can see, ng-view is not associated to header-component in some way.

Let's say that ng-view controll now screen is:

```
// some-screen.js
$scope.foo = "bar";
```

And I want to display `bar` in the header.

I can do this both with $rootScope (without any event) or using the $broadcast event.

First method - using the $rootScope - as it is - without just anything:

```
// some-screen.js 
$rootScope.foo = "bar";

// header.js 
app.directive("headerComponent", ($rootScope) => {
  return {
    templateUrl: "/structure/header/header.html",
    scope: {},
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log($rootScope.foo) // "bar"
    }
  }
});
```

Second method - using the $broadcast event

```
// some-screen.js 
$rootScope.$emit("SomeNameOfTheEvent", $scope.foo);

// header.js 
app.directive("headerComponent", ($rootScope) => {
  return {
    templateUrl: "/structure/header/header.html",
    scope: {},
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
      $rootScope.$on("SomeNameOfTheEvent", function(event, info) {
        console.log(info.foo) // "bar"
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Now notice two things while using the $broadcast event:

1. You need to specify name for this event - in big app this can be tricky - since 
   you probably ain't going to remember the names you throw while coding.
   And sitting and think of good names is a waste of time.
   You will probably need to make a documentation in order to re-use the event name from other places 
   in the app - otherwise you will mistakely try to use the same event but with wrong names.
2. They are both doing the same - $broadcast just takes more code to function.

What am I missing, AngularJS probably created the $broadcast event for something.

Comment: You say "think of good names is a waste of time". That is a shortsided view. Whether it is an event name or a variable name, thinking of good names makes code easier to understand, debug, test, and maintain. Good names save time over the life of the code.

Answer (score 1):

> $emit dispatches an event upwards ... $broadcast dispatches an event
>   downwards

**Detailed explanation**

`$rootScope.$emit` only lets other `$rootScope` listeners catch it. This is good when you don't want every $scope to get it. Mostly a high level communication. Think of it as adults talking to each other in a room so the kids can't hear them.

`$rootScope.$broadcast` is a method that lets pretty much everything hear it. This would be the equivalent of parents yelling that dinner is ready so everyone in the house hears it.

`$scope.$emit` is when you want that `$scope` and all its parents and `$rootScope` to hear the event. This is a child whining to their parents at home (but not at a grocery store where other kids can hear).

`$scope.$broadcast` is for the `$scope` itself and its children. This is a child whispering to its stuffed animals so their parents can't hear.

Comment: I am asking about binding the data directly via `$rootScope` vs casting them using `$emit` or `$broadcast`.